# addCruise() -- NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

Not to revisit old topics, but I'm working on a project for a course and I'm repeatedly encountering this error at one particular segment, where I've got various other bits of code in the *same format* that are giving me no grief whatsoever.

```
public static void addCruise() {

    Scanner newCruiseInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the new cruise: ");
    String newCruiseName = newCruiseInput.nextLine();
    
    // Verify no cruise of same name already exists
    for (Cruise eachCruise: cruiseList) {
        if (eachCruise.getCruiseName().equalsIgnoreCase(newCruiseName)) {
            System.out.println("A cruise by that name already exists. Exiting to menu...");
            return; // Quits addCruise() method processing
        }
    }
    
    // Get name of cruise ship
    Scanner cruiseShipInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter name of cruise ship: ");
    String cruiseShipName = cruiseShipInput.nextLine();
    cruiseShipInput.close();
    
    // Get port of departure
    Scanner cruiseDepartureInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter cruise's departure port: ");
    String departPort = cruiseDepartureInput.nextLine();
    cruiseDepartureInput.close();
```

So, as above, I've got no trouble with anything ***up until*** that `cruiseDepartureInput` scanner. But before I get to provide the input for that line, Eclipse is throwing the error, which in full reads:

Enter cruise's departure port: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

- at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
- at Driver.addCruise(Driver.java:295)
- at Driver.main(Driver.java:38)

Why would I be facing this exception here, but not anywhere else in the rest of the program? Everything else tested and functioned as expected, but this particular input is turning into a headache.

Also, forgive my error formatting, best I could do with how little the editor wanted to cooperate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line and you will notice that your issue will go away (for now):

```
cruiseShipInput.close();
```

The problem here is that you are closing the `System.in` stream, which means you can no longer take any input. So when you attempt to start a new scanner using `System.in` it will fail because the stream no longer exists.

For a simple project the correct answer is to not close the scanner, or better yet, only create a single scanner that you use throughout your entire project:

```
public static void addCruise() {

    //Create a single scanner that you can use throughout your project.
    //If you have multiple classes then need to use input then create a wrapper class to manage the scanner inputs
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Now do the rest of your inputs
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the new cruise: ");
    String newCruiseName = inputScanner.nextLine();
    
    // Verify no cruise of same name already exists
    for (Cruise eachCruise: cruiseList) {
        if (eachCruise.getCruiseName().equalsIgnoreCase(newCruiseName)) {
            System.out.println("A cruise by that name already exists. Exiting to menu...");
            return; // Quits addCruise() method processing
        }
    }
    
    // Get name of cruise ship
    System.out.print("Enter name of cruise ship: ");
    String cruiseShipName = inputScanner.nextLine();
    
    // Get port of departure
    System.out.print("Enter cruise's departure port: ");
    String departPort = inputScanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: This is the first I've learned that calling a .close() on any scanner completely closes out system.in. I had thought it would simply close input for the specified Scanner object. This worked out great though, thanks for the quick reply